# Discrete Log solve using Index-Calculus producing incorrect 'r' value.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

I have a discrete log that I need to solve to aid in a Cryptography problem, that deals with both programming and mathematics, so I was unsure where to post this problem, feel free to move me if needed. I must use Index-Calculus to solve this discrete log. Here's the setup, my attempt, and my code (producing the wrong 'r' value).

Let $p=10007$. $5$ is a primitive root. It can be shown that $L_5(2)=6578, L_5(3)=6190, L_5(7)=1301$. Use these facts to find $L_5(100)$

So, I have the fact that

$100\times5^r\equiv7\times3\times2\mod 10007$

$\implies L_5(100)\equiv-r+L_5(7)+L_5(3)+L_5(2)\mod 10006$

And $L_5(7)+L_5(3)+L_5(2)$ are known, so I now just need to find a $r$ s.t.

$100\times5^r\equiv7\times3\times2\equiv42\mod 10007$

So I wrote a program that basically just loops through $j$ for $0\leqslant j\lt p$, and then calculates $100*5^j\equiv ans \mod 10007$ and checks if $ans = 42$. When it is equal to 42, it prints the j used. This is producing an answer of $r=j=378$, however this is **NOT** correct, as $100\times5^{378}\not\equiv 42\mod 10007$. The correct answer is $r=j=911$.

Where have I gone wrong? Or else, is there an easier way to solve this problem? (Using Index-Calculus, I can solve it using Baby Step Giant Step, or Pohlig-Hellman algorithm.

Comment: It seems you aren't clear about how discrete logs work. If my answer doesn't help clarify that then let me know and I can elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called a discrete **log** because $\,L(xy)\equiv L(x)+L(y)\ \pmod{p\!-\!1},\ $ therefore

$$\begin{align} L(2)&\,\equiv\, 6579,\ L(5)\equiv 1\\[.2em]
 \Rightarrow\, L((2\cdot 5)^2) &\,\equiv\, 2(L(2)+L(5)) \\[.2em]
 &\equiv\, 2(6578+1)\end{align}\qquad \qquad\qquad\quad\!$$

**Remark** $ $ While you can ignore the logs and instead work with powers of $5$ as in Robert's answer, this likely is *completely opposite* of the goal of the exercise, which is likely intended to teach you how to convert such *multiplicative* problems into simpler *additive* problems in $\,\Bbb Z_{p-1} = $ integers $\bmod p\!-\!1\ $  (which is the *raison d'etre of* this index calculus).

Comment: Whether you write it as $L(2^2 \cdot 5^2) = 2 L(2) + 2 $ or $2^2 \cdot 5^2 = 5^{2 \cdot L(2) + 2}$ is a matter of taste.  The actual computation is the same.

Comment: @Robert Of course. But I don't agree that is is simply a matter of "taste". Rather. it is a matter of *pedagogy*. That the student titled it "discrete log solve" surely means they were taught to solve these problems using discrete logs. Your answer is of little help in that regard since it completely eliminates the log viewpoint.

Answer (score 2):

$100 = 2^2 \cdot 5^2$.  If $2 \equiv 5^{6578} \bmod p$, then 
$2^2 \cdot 5^2 \equiv 5^{2 \cdot 6578 + 2} \equiv 5^{3152}\bmod p$.