# Seeking for an algebraic proof of a problem of number theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, discrete-logarithms

This is a problem in a test stands as a simulation of the NCEE (the college entrance examination of China), it starts by giving a definition of the discrete log:

*Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $X=\lbrace 1,2,...,p-1\rbrace$, define $u\otimes v$ to be $uv\bmod{p}$ for $u,v\in X$, and define $u^{m,\otimes}$ to be $u^m\bmod{p}$. Now let $a\in X$ and $1, a, a^{2,\otimes},...,a^{p-2,\otimes}$ are pairwise different, if $a^{n,\otimes}=b(n\in\lbrace0,1,...,p-2\rbrace)$, we say that $n$ is the discrete logarithm of $a$ to the base $b$, written $n=\log(p)_a b$.*

Then it asks to prove:

- *Let $m_1,m_2\in\lbrace0,1,...,p-2\rbrace$, define $m_1\oplus m_2=(m_1+m_2)\bmod{(p-1)}$, prove that $\log(p)_a(b\otimes c)=\log(p)_a b\oplus \log(p)_a c$.*
- *Let $n=\log(p)_a b$, for $x\in X$ and $k\in\lbrace 1,2,...,p-2\rbrace$, let $y_1=a^{k,\otimes}$, $y_2=x\otimes b^{k,\otimes}$, proves that $x=y_2\otimes y_1^{n(p-2), \otimes}$*

**My problem: Is there a proof of this problem using algebraic approach, not only number theory.**

**Background:** I apologize for the non-standard and confusing notation here, but this is literally how it looks on the test paper.  This is at first glance a problem of number theory on which I don't have any background (In fact any students should not be supposed to equipped such background in a normal senior school here because they never appear on the textbook), since I do have some algebra background and to me it has a strong algebraic feel, I tried to prove it using some group theory but failed because of the lack of knowledge from the number theory part. I check the answer and it seems that if you are of number theory or cryptography background, then this problem will become rather basic. But the answer used a pure number-theoretic approach, I'm wondering is there a way to prove it by leveraging the tools from algebras?

Comment: I would definitely have not made it into college if this was an example question from an entrance exam.

Comment: @abissu Well it is pretty weird because in here, number theory was never a part of the math education from junior to senior school, it  just never appear, this is the 19th problem of the test paper, and normally the test paper would contain 3 extra problems which are sequences, calculus, and analytic geometry, respectively, but in this test the paper stops in this problem, so I guess the creator of this paper admits its difficulty and weirdness :)

Comment: The notation is just awfully non standard, even though I am familiar with the above it took me a non zero time to decipher what is meant :/. I probably also wouldn't have passed such an entrance exam after high school.

Comment: Well first time I saw it I thought it was some kind of algebraic sum and product, until I find it seems to be irrelevant...

Comment: Working in the ring $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is algebra and number theory at the same time. There is no difference. So "not only number theory" is not possible. $p$ is a prime, so this is definitely number theory. But an identity or congruence is algebra.

Comment: @DietrichBurde field :P

Comment: @eulersgroupie It is a ring (every field is a ring).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know but imo it should say field in your comment.

Comment: @eulersgroupie No, the point is that algebra treats this as rings first, because usually it is more generally $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ for all natural numbers $n$ (and then it is not always a field). But because of $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_n^{e_n}$ as prime powers, it is very much number theory as well.

Comment: As I recall, you can prove this using generators. I don't think you can escape using some variation of Fermat's Little Theorem. Here, there's a lot of overlap between Group Theory and Number Theory.

Comment: Are you familiar with groups?  This boils down to showing that an element of multiplicative order $\,m\, (= p\!-\!1\,$ here) generates a cyclic group isomorphic to the additive group of $\,\Bbb Z_m =$ integers $\!\bmod m.\ \ $

Comment: For a simple  worked example see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3165157/242). To learn more see  [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) and [index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm). $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for the inspiration! However could you please provide some more detail because I really haven't face any number theory problems or definitions, properties, theorems before which makes me have some problem in translating the original problem properly.